# Updating Cordova Version with terminal

Tags: android, cordova

I have a phonegap app whos files have an outdated cordova version, specifically 3.4.0. I am trying to update to the latest version because of the security vulnerability.

[image]

In my terminal, I have went to the project directory which is on my desktop:

### `/Users/chrono/Desktop/App \ 2/Cordova3.4.0`

It keeps telling me the cordova is up to date with newest 5.4.0 but when I check cordova.js, that is not correct. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: Remove the cordova via CLI and then reinstall. It will install the latest cordova without any error

Answer (score 0):

When you update cordova you update the CLI version, but it doesn't update the projects you created, to update a project go to the project's root folder and type

```
cordova platform update android
```

Comment: yes, for some reason it's telling me it does not exist. My project root folder is the /Users/chrono/Desktop/App \ 2/Cordova3.4.0

Comment: http://imgur.com/MvI4n38 - first it said no platform exists. so i created a new platform and it made a /platforms directory in the same section as App 2 which is on my desktop. It seems like it doesn't know that there is an android folder in App 2 -> Cordova 3.4.0

Comment: so, it says you have cordova android 4.1.1, that's the version that cordova CLI 5.4.0 includes.

Comment: yes, i know.. but my actual project folder isn't being updated even when trying to update the platform. see my directory and this image: http://i.imgur.com/p9lr7Uz.png

Comment: the info.txt doesn't exists anymore (I don't even remember having it on previous versions), so it won't be updated. You have to check the cordova.js inside platforms/android/platform_www

Comment: yeah, the cordova.js is at 3.4.0. Any idea on how to update it? It's very deprecated or do I have to do a new cordova install and port things over

Comment: try with ```cordova platform rm android``` and then ```cordova platform add android```